# Can't run PowerShell script in Azure DevOps Pipeline 'parse error'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

So, I'm new to Azure Devops (but not Azure or PowerShell). I've got two scripts as tasks in my pipeline, the first runs perfectly (Note: no az module commands). The second one fails (It has one Az call). The error I get in the pipeline is:

```
ParserError: /home/vsts/work/_temp/3f7b3ce1-6afb-46f3-b00d-1efe35fbac71.ps1:5
Line |
   5 |  } else {
     |  ~
     | Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
```

Here is the thing... I don't have '} else {' in my script or at least, I removed it and got the same error.

So whatever is causing this is more fundamental than my script. I assumed that '/home/vsts/work/_temp/3f7b3ce1-6afb-46f3-b00d-1efe35fbac71.ps1' was my script copied to the remote syste, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Is there any way, I can find out what that file is?

The task is 'PowerShell@2' with 'pwsh: true' set.
Thanks!

YAML:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'Pay-As-You-Go(<guid>)'
    subscriptionId: '<guid>'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: 'project-Test'
    location: 'East US 2'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: 'deploy.template.json'
    csmParametersFile: 'deploy.parameters.json'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
    deploymentOutputs: 'DeploymentOutput'

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Get-ArmDeploymentOutput.ps1 -ArmOutputString '$(DeploymentOutput)' -MakeOutput -ErrorAction Stop
    pwsh: true
  displayName: Get-ArmDeploymentOutput

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Set-AzWebAppIPRestriction.ps1 -Priority 100 -Action 'Allow' -WebAppId '$(WebAppId)' -PipId '$(gwpipId)'' -ErrorAction Stop
    pwsh: true
  displayName: Set-AzWebAppIPRestriction
```

Comment: You need to provide the YAML, the `<guid>.ps1` filename is just the file that gets created for your inline script.

Comment: I've added the YAML.

Comment: Those aren't inline scripts. Those are files. Try changing the `targetType` to `filePath`. If you get path errors, insert a `- pwsh: Get-ChildItem $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) -Recurse` to get the directory output and help resolve path issues.

Answer (score 0):

I found there is an extra `'` in `-PipId '$(gwpipId)''` in the script of your second powershell task. Maybe it caused the error.

`script: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Set-AzWebAppIPRestriction.ps1 -Priority 100 -Action 'Allow' -WebAppId '$(WebAppId)' -PipId '$(gwpipId)'' -ErrorAction Stop`

Since you were running your scripts in .ps1 file. You should change the `targetType` parameter of [powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) to `filePath`. And set .ps1 file in the `filePath` parameter. See below example:

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Set-AzWebAppIPRestriction.ps1'
    arguments: '-Priority 100 -Action "Allow" -WebAppId "$(WebAppId)" -PipId "$(gwpipId)" -ErrorAction Stop'
    pwsh: true
```

If you are using azure powershell module in your scripts. You can use [Azure powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops) instead of powershell task..